# which database model should I use?

Tags: php, forms, post, multidimensional-array, submit

I have a contact form with different section like:

My form has three fixed fields `class1, class2, class3` and there is a button through which user can add more input fields, So how do I structure my `database` to store those additional fields
and these forms are user specific i.e there is a user table as well

```
FORM ID | USER ID
   1         1  
   2         2
   3         1
```

So there can be multiple form as well for a user.

```
<input name="x1" id="section[class1][section_name]" />
<input name="x2" id="section[class2][section_name]" />
<input name="x3" id="section[class3][section_name]" />
```

above input field are used to store section name .
I am new in database structure so Any kind of link or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: @downvoter atleast give reason for down vote , so that I can improve

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea I had:

First, create a table called custom_fields with the following fields:

- field_name of type varchar/text
- field_value of type varchar/text
- field_type of type varchar/text
- form_id of type integer

Second, make sure that your forms table has a user_id of type integer in it and that your users table that the user does indeed has an id.

Now, just use the ids to store the values to the appropriate form.